# Fusing RSSI and Time of Flight values

Tags: signal-processing, wireless, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I have RSSI(Received Signal Strength Values) and TOF (Time of Flight values). Both these parameters give me distance information between the Anchor and Tag and are effected by different channel conditions.

Is there any method to fuse these values, so that the final distance between the Anchor and Tag gets better?

I tried Adaptive weighting.

Comment: And what come out of the adaptive weighting?

Comment: Adaptive weighting of the distance values obtained from RSSI and TOF .

Comment: RSSI values are affected by building partition walls. whereas the ToF values are relatively less affected or unaffected by partition walls. The plot between these can be helpful

Comment: @KarthikBalaguru : you are right there are different channel parameters effect these values differently. But i am wondering how to make more generalized approach, such that overall accuracy increases.